# Does Amazon SNS provide user mail open event?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I did some RnD , but was unable to fetch proper info.
All the events i got was complaints,bounces and delivery event notifications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you wanted to ask about SES
No it does not provide open events notification out of the box. You will have to write your own logic

Refer this blogpost for tracking email open events
https://blog.aweber.com/email-marketing/how-are-email-opens-tracked.htm